# How can we test performance of a mobile application(both android and IOS)

Tags: android, ios, testing, performance-testing

I need to test the performance of a mobile application.
I have used jmeter tool to test it's services and APIs, but we want to test it's performance in device as well. is there any tool using which we can test the performance of a mobile application.

A single open source tool which can help with both applications i.e. android and IOS is preferred.

If there is any another way, with which we can test the performance of a application is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

[Yandex.Tank](https://github.com/yandex/yandex-tank/) has an appium plugin (that starts appium before your performance test and stops after the end of the test) and [BFG](http://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#bfg) plugin that can run Python scenarios (here is a simple [example](https://gist.github.com/direvius/e38f8cec40e5b61b36753ef4edd5373b)) as loadtests. You could also use a python binding for [UIautomator](https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator) instead of Appium in your scripts. You can use [Overload](https://overload.yandex.net) to analyze the results of your tests. Monitoring metrics can be gathered with [Telegraf](http://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#telegraf) plugin using custom config with `adb` commands in it to read the `/proc` file system on the phone. For example:

```
    <Monitoring>
      <Host address="localhost" interval="1">
      <Custom measure="call" label="memory">adb shell 'grep MemFree /proc/meminfo' | awk '{print $2}'</Custom>
      <Custom measure="call" label="dsk_data_free">adb shell dumpsys diskstats | grep Data-Free | sed s/%//g | awk '{print $7}'</Custom>

      ... etc ...

    </Monitoring>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'll surely give it a try, but as i am not good with python, i'll prefer a tool which needs no much coding skills.